# Who were the children of Jacob Fisher and Sarah Hodges?

Tags: united-states, 18th-century, baptism-records, new-england

[Page 27](http://www.americanancestors.org/PageDetail.aspx?recordId=142685938) of the Sharon, Massachusetts Vital Records show Jacob Fisher and his wife Sarah had a son Jacob born 30 Apr 1776:

> Jacob, s. of Jacob and Sarah, Apr. 30, 1776

Page 94 of those records show a [marriage record](http://www.americanancestors.org/PageDetail.aspx?recordId=142689066) of Jacob Fisher to Sarah Hodges on 7 Oct 1773:

> Fisher ... Jacob and Sarah Hodges Oct 7, 1773.

I am presuming they are the same as the parents in the previous record.

The reason I originally asked this question is that through the DNA testing, I found I shared common DNA with someone. We both have Fishers in our ancestry (my paternal grandmother). However we have not yet been able to connect the dots and so we are trying to extend our Fisher line to find common overlap. The reason for asking about the children is look for links with my shared-dna correspondent. Note if we can find a potential connection, the dna evidence may be collaborating, non-definitive, evidence.

I will ask in another question (and update this one with reference) about the parents of Jacob Sr. Similarly I'll ask in a separate question about whether the Jacob Jr in this link is the Jacob who sired my line. My ancestor (speculating the Jacob Jr above) was in Worcester, MA but there was alot of movement to Worcester in this period (Worcester being a major mustering point for Massachusetts during the  American Revolution) so speculating either Jacob Sr moved there with family or Jacob Jr moved there later.